# Entry Validation Extra Arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a set of entry boxes created in a for loop and recorded in a dictionary that I want to validate independently. The loop that creates them follows:

```
vcmd = (self.register(self.VE), '%P')
for pos in [(i,j) for i in range(9) for j in range(9)]:
            self.inputDict[pos] = tk.StringVar()
            self.entryDict[pos] = tk.Entry(font = ('Arial', 20, 'bold'),
                                           textvariable = self.inputDict[pos],
                                           borderwidth = 1, width = 2,
                                           justify = 'center',
                                           validatecommand = vcmd,
                                           validate = 'key')
```

And the code for self.VE is here:

```
def VE(self, P, pos):
    if P in [str(i) for i in map(chr,range(49,58))]:
        self.solution.insertVal(P,pos)
    elif P == '': self.solution.removeVal(pos)
    return P in [str(i) for i in map(chr,range(49,58))]+['']
```

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to get VE to take arguments that are not included in the list provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content/4140988#4140988), duplicated below:

```
# valid percent substitutions (from the Tk entry man page)
# %d = Type of action (1=insert, 0=delete, -1 for others)
# %i = index of char string to be inserted/deleted, or -1
# %P = value of the entry if the edit is allowed
# %s = value of entry prior to editing
# %S = the text string being inserted or deleted, if any
# %v = the type of validation that is currently set
# %V = the type of validation that triggered the callback
#      (key, focusin, focusout, forced)
# %W = the tk name of the widget
```

I believe I'll need to make my change to the line defining `vcmd`, but I don't know what change to make to allow the validation command to take the position of the entry (that is, the value of `pos`) as well as the attempted input. How do I add an argument to the validation command that isn't in that list?

Comment: What do you mean by "the position of the entry"? Are you wanting to pass in the value of `pos`?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you give to the `validatecommand` is a tuple of the registered command and any arguments you want to pass to the command. Therefore, you can do something like this:

```
    vcmd = self.register(self.VE)

    for pos in ...:
        self.entryDict[pos] = tk.Entry(..., 
                                       validatecommand=(vcmd, "%P", pos), 
                                       ...)
    ...

def VE(self, P, pos):
    print "P: %s pos: %s" % (P, pos)
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. May I ask why the command must be registered before it can be set as the validatecommand function? At first I thought it might be to make it a valid callback, but lambda functions work just as well, at least for things that don't take special arguments. Also, is formatting in the '%P' string representative of the new input? I don't understand how strings can be valid argument keywords. I thought keywords had to be variable names.

Comment: Now this is weird. After adjusting my code, I tried your answer and came up with a call to pos in VE that returned a string, not the tuple value that pos takes in self.entryDict.keys(). It's not a problem to extract the data from the pos string to reform the pos tuple, but what coerces it to a string? It doesn't even return the same string as str(pos).

Comment: This data is being passed to an underlying Tcl interpreter, which has no knowledge of python datatypes. In Tcl "everything is a string", so the translation is happening at the python/Tcl boundary.